# High-resolution, hyperspectral satellite imaging?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images, biology

I am hoping to expand my (biology-focused) research to include satellite data. For this, I'd need satellite imaging that includes multiple values in the visible spectrum (specifically, above 490nm) and extends slightly into the infrared (710nm). I have tried MERIS and Hyperion, but the resolution was insufficient (my area of interest is a lake ~300m x 55m). I've had a brief look at Worldview 2/3, but the spectral bands seem too wide.

Does anything like this exist, and is it freely available for research use?

Comment: [anything here of use?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=satellite+imag*)

Answer (score 1):

if you are based in the U.K. I could provide to you hyperspectral airplane imagery with a high resolution. Let me know if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

The GFZ Potsdam, a large research institute in Germany, has several groups  working on hyperspectral data.

This page http://www.enmap.org/flights.html lists a table with several datasets from Europe, acquired 2011-2014.

Most of the DOI links on that page lead to the library of GFZ Potsdam, which offers a data download service. However, for some reason most authors have put an embargo on their hyperspectral datasets. You need to contact them personally first.

From the [report](http://doi.org/10.2312/enmap.2017.001):

> For  data  access,  the  interested  user  shall  fill  in  the  contact  form  at  the  DOI  Landing  Page  of  the  respective flight campaign and will then be provided with an FTP link for download. If there is no DOI available yet, the user may contact the responsible person listed in the Tableview (Contact).

---

Unrelated: Maybe [pangaea.de](https://www.pangaea.de) has some interesting [hyperspectral imagery datasets](https://www.pangaea.de/?q=Hyperspectral+imaging&offset=10) available to  you as well?